# How to search for a string in a file and print the line containing that string?

Tags: c++, string, file, search, find

I have to search for the string look_for in file named as record.txt but the code doesn't work.

Each time I give a value to look_for that is present in the file it says record not found

```
string look_for, line;
    in.open("record.txt");
    cout<<"what is registration no of student ?";
    cin>>look_for;
    while(getline(in,line))
    {
        if(line.find(look_for)!= string::npos)
        {
            cout<<" record found "<<endl<<endl;
            break;
        }
        else cout<<"record not found ";
    }
```

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: ...which should include a short example file and a `look_for` value.

Comment: (and obvious check first: `in` is still valid after you called `open` on it, right?)

Comment: I think `look_for` has line-feed, or some other characters at the end - which is breaking the `find`

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine, but you don't check if the file could actually be opened.

Modify your code like this:

```
  ...
  in.open("record.txt");

  if (!in.is_open())
  {
    cout << "Could not open file" << endl;
    return 1;
  }

  cout << "what is registration no of student ?";
  ...
```

The reasons why the file could not be open may include:

- the file does not exist
- the file is not in the directory where the executable runs

Comment: i have tried it and i am sure the file is being successfully opened....

Comment: Cannot reproduce. Post a [mcve] (you been asked that already). Maybe the problem is in the code you didn't show (it happens all the time here).

Comment: string look_for, line,line2;
        in.open("record.txt");
        cout<<"what is registration no of student ?";
        cin>>look_for;
        if(!in.is_open())
        {
            cout << "Could not open file" << endl;
        }
        while(getline(in,line))
        {
            if(line.find(look_for)!= string::npos)
            {
                cout<<" record found "<<endl<<endl;
                break;
            }
            else cout<<"record not found ";
        }

Comment: @KaleemKhattak please don't post code in comments. Edit your question and put the whole program (including main, the #includes etc.) there. Please read and understand this: [mcve].

Comment: this is so much annoying

Comment: i cant edit my code each time it tells your code is not properly indented

Comment: @KaleemKhattak sorry I don't understand what you mean. Giving up.

Comment: when i edit my code it says "your code is not properly indented"

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the file is opened and the `line` that is returned by `getline` has the correct value, also check that the file has UTF-8 encoding.

Comment: what do you mean by correct value and what is utf 8 encoding how to check it

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>`
using namespace std;

int main()
{
   string look_for, line;
   int lineNumber = 0;
   ifstream in("record.txt");
   if (!in.is_open())
   {
       cout << "Couldn't open file" << endl;
       return -1;
   }

   cout << "what is registration no of student ?\t";
   cin >> look_for;
   while (getline(in, line))
   {
       if (line.find(look_for) != string::npos)
       {
           cout << "Line:\t" << lineNumber << "\t[ " << look_for << " ] found in line [ " << line << " ]" << endl;
           lineNumber = 0;
           break;
       }
       lineNumber++;
   }

   if (lineNumber != 0)
       cout << "[ " << look_for << " ] not found" << endl;

   return 0;
 }
```